# Google Cloud Messaging in iOS

Tags: ios

Hi i want to implement GCM in iOS and i have my *SenderID* but i dont know where i have to implement *SenderID*.This is my entire code for GCM integration.i need *TOKEN* value.so please guide me to get it done.

**Appdelegate :**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()
{
    NSDictionary *RegistrationOptions;
    NSString *GcmSenderID;
    GGLInstanceIDTokenHandler registrationHandler;
}
@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UIUserNotificationType allNotificationTypes=(UIUserNotificationTypeSound|UIUserNotificationTypeBadge);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings=[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:allNotificationTypes categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication]registerForRemoteNotifications];

    return YES;
}
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken{

    // Create a config and set a delegate that implements the GGLInstaceIDDelegate protocol.
    GGLInstanceIDConfig *instanceIDConfig = [GGLInstanceIDConfig defaultConfig];
    instanceIDConfig.delegate = self;
    // Start the GGLInstanceID shared instance with the that config and request a registration
    // token to enable reception of notifications
    [[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] startWithConfig:instanceIDConfig];
    RegistrationOptions = @{kGGLInstanceIDRegisterAPNSOption:deviceToken,
                             kGGLInstanceIDAPNSServerTypeSandboxOption:@YES};
    [[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] tokenWithAuthorizedEntity:GcmSenderID
                                                        scope:kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM
                                                      options:RegistrationOptions
                                                      handler:registrationHandler];

}

- (void)onTokenRefresh {
    // A rotation of the registration tokens is happening, so the app needs to request a new token.
    NSLog(@"The GCM registration token needs to be changed.");
    [[GGLInstanceID sharedInstance] tokenWithAuthorizedEntity:GcmSenderID
                                                        scope:kGGLInstanceIDScopeGCM
                                                      options:RegistrationOptions
                                                      handler:registrationHandler];


}
```

Comment: please let me know the answer

Answer (score 0):

Its pretty late answer.But it will help someone in future.

You just have to upload `apns certificate` (developer and production) and get the `gcm config` file and add it to your project (drag and drop to your project).

The following code which you should call in the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` will automatically fetch the `_gcmSenderID` from the config file.

`_gcmSenderID = [[[GGLContext sharedInstance] configuration] gcmSenderID];`

***Here is a*** [sample quick start project](https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/ios/gcm) ***for you to start with.(both swift and objective-C).Everything is well explained in this sample app.Let me know if you have any doubts.***